# Is there any better IDOMImplementation other than MSXML?

Tags: xml, delphi

There are 3 IDOMImplementation available in Delphi:

1. MSXML
2. Xerces XML
3. ADOM XML v4

MSXML is the default IDOMImplementation.

My test is count the time need to load a 10MB xml file.  I use a Delphi unit generated from a XSD using XML data binding to load the xml file.  This unit has 3 common function:

```
function Getmenubar(Doc: IXMLDocument): IXMLMenubarType;
function Loadmenubar(const FileName: WideString): IXMLMenubarType;
function Newmenubar: IXMLMenubarType;
```

I learn from the web that some comment that MSXML's overhead is high that it doesn't perform if compare to other XML parser.  However, my study shows that MSXML is the best among others.  Xerces XML 2nd and ADOM XML v4 the worst:

1. MSXML - 0.6410 seconds
2. Xerces XML - 2.4220 seconds
3. ADOM XML v4 - 67.50 seconds

I also come across with OmniXML that claim to have much better performance compare to MSXML but I never success using it with the unit generated by XML data binding.

Is there any other vendor that implement IDOMImplementation of Delphi that work much better than MSXML?  I am using Delphi 2010 and Windows 7.

Comment: Are you sure you need a DOM parser? SAX parsers are faster.

Comment: I don't know too much about XML, but I do know computing, and I know this as a general rule: If there's a Microsoft version and alternatives, at least one of the alternatives *will* be better.

Comment: Why is OmniXML not working for you? I use it in a lot of products with great success. And yes it is fater than MSXML.

Comment: If you look at this unit in VCL source: msxmldom.pas, you will see the unit register the DOM vendor in initialize part.  We may then set DefaultDOMVendor (a variable define in xmldom.pas) to specify the DOM vendor to use when parsing the XML stream.  Yes, I need to use DOM as I access my XML stream via objects generated by XML data binding.

Comment: Did you stick with MSXML?  (Or find any other alternatives?)

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool named NativeXML (recently goes opensource)
http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html

Answer (score 1):

There is [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com/) that is faster than MSXML and is OpenSource. It is MSXML complicant, so the switch is very easy. Event the interface names are the same. Then there is [SimpleStorage](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/simplestorage/) which expands the OmniXML interfaces, so that working with XML becomes very easy. Look at the demos and at blog posts about SimpleStorage usage. Just bear in mind that more complex operations in SimpleStorage sacrifice a little of the speed for ease of use and power.